# How would I bind a list of objects to a standard MS GridView in a WinForms Application?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

This is a very basic question - I have a List(Of MyClass) in a VB.net WinForms application.

MyClass contains two public string properties.

I would like to bind a List(Of MyClass) to a plain MS GridView on a WinForm so that items added to the List(Of MyClass) appear in the MS GridView.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with vb syntax, but in c#, you can easily bind the list as a datasource to the datagridview. something like this (c#):

```
        List<Class2> list = new List<Class2>();
        list.Add(new Class2 { test1 = "test", test2 = "test2" });
        list.Add(new Class2 { test1 = "test", test2 = "test2" });
        list.Add(new Class2 { test1 = "test", test2 = "test2" });
        list.Add(new Class2 { test1 = "test", test2 = "test2" });
        list.Add(new Class2 { test1 = "test", test2 = "test2" });
        list.Add(new Class2 { test1 = "test", test2 = "test2" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
```

i think it's not really difficult for you to reproduce this in vb.net.

Comment: This is essentially what I already have. The items initially added to the list show up in the grid, however, no addition or changes to the list show up in the gridview. Even if I reset the GridView Datasource to the List after the list changes. My List class inherits a List(Of WordPairs) where WordPairs is a class that contains two public string properties, a simple AddPair method that calls Add with two words and raises a PropertyChanged event.

Is there a way to have the GridView respond to changes in the GridView.DataSource?

Comment: edit your initial posting and show some of your existing code. i don't know how you implement your current datasource update. i think it's quite obvious that you need to populate changes from your datasource to consumable collections/controls.